# execute linux command in java

Tags: java, linux, cron

i want to execute the command **crontab file.txt** in java.

What is the procedure...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("contrab file.txt")`

Answer (score 5):

[ProcessBuilder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) is your friend.

Answer (score 1):

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("crontab file.txt")
```

Answer (score 1):

linux commands are essentially programs. You can simply run them using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("crontab file.txt");`